# Pronto: gitlab gem not found error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I have a **rails project** in a `github repo`, and a `CI server` for running tests.

The thing is, I added `rubocop/pronto` to get some feedback about the code style (not need to post messages on Github for now, only to run it locally to get warnings about my changes), and **pronto has the gitlab gem as a dependency**.

Given my CI server doesn't have the gitlab gem installed (because there is no need to), the build is failing with the message:

> gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize': Could not find gitlab-3.6.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

These are added to my Gemfile.lock after running `bundle`

```
pronto (0.8.2)
  gitlab (~> 3.6, >= 3.4.0)
...
gitlab (3.6.1)
  httparty
  terminal-table
```

Is there any way I can install pronto without installing the gitlab gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is, you can't use the gem without gitlab, since [it is a requirement in the gem's main file](https://github.com/mmozuras/pronto/blob/96bba3d9b16baef5c07754047fb1f46b33a0670b/lib/pronto.rb#L3).

You could fork the gem and remove Gitlab from that file. I didn't comb through the code, but this might break more things. It should be possible to remove the references to Gitlab without breaking the core functionality though.